# Query blobs in Blob storage

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I have serialized text data that is stored in a blob inside Azure blob storage. The text is basically key/value data. I am wondering if there is a way to easily query the blob without exploding the data into another table/database or pulling the blob into memory?

Answer (score 3):

Azure Blob storage has no API to query data within the blob - it's just dumb storage.  See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd135733.aspx) for the Blob Storage API.  You're essentially stuck reading, deserializing and grabbing your value(s).

Perhaps Azure [table storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-tables/) would be a better fit for this application?  That at least keeps things in the realm of an Azure storage account rather than needing to pull in a SQL Server instance.

Comment: Seems the above mentioned statement for Azure Blob `it's just dumb storage` seems holds true but there is [`BlockBlobClient.query()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/storage-blob/blockblobclient?view=azure-node-latest#query_string__BlockBlobQueryOptions_) for querying on Azure Blob data. Please share if you have any way found to query blob data or blobs using some query or filters.

Answer (score 0):

One option you could consider is to use [Data Lake Analytics](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/data-lake-analytics-manage-use-portal/#manage-account-data-sources), as it supports Azure Blobs as data source. 
Depending on what your preferred way of accessing the data is, you can use PowerShell, .NET SDK etc. to query the data...

Answer (score 0):

Update: you can use `blockBlobClient.query(..)` to run simple queries on JSON or CSV blob data.